# Can't install wine32 packages on Debian testing (Bookworm)

Tags: debian, wine

I try to install wine32 packages on Debian testing. Although on one of my machines this goes without any problems on this one I can't get it going:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade 
sudo apt install wine
```

This will install the following packages:

```
libwine wine wine64
```

And recommend `wine32`

But `sudo apt install wine32` gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: librtmp1 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated     breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

#### UPDATE:

Trying to install `libcurl3-gnutls:i386` gives the same result:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3-gnutls:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: librtmp1 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I wasn't able to resolve this. Any ideas?

Comment: And how about `sudo apt install librtmp1:i386`?

Comment: @StephenKitt It gives me the same message, this is odd: `libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: librtmp1 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable`

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by manually downloading `librtmp1:i386` and installing it with `dpkg`, this gave a message of missing dependencies. The latter I could then resolve by installing those packages via `apt`:

```
sudo apt install libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libhogweed6:i386 libnettle8:i386 zlib1g:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libffi8:i386
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3-gnutls:i386
```

And at last:

```
sudo apt install wine32
```

I don't get why the hack apt wasn't able to resolve this dependencies it self. But if everybody else stumbles over this problem. This is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on my debian with a bullseye version. I could not install win32 because of librtmp1:

```
# apt install librtmp1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: librtmp1 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable
```

I tried to manually install i386 version of librtmp1 with dpkg. It failed but give me some hints to solve the issue:

```
# dpkg -i ~avd/Downloads/librtmp1_2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package librtmp1:i386.
(Reading database ... 424606 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../librtmp1_2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2_i386.deb ...
De-configuring librtmp1:amd64 (2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7) ...
Unpacking librtmp1:i386 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2) ...
dpkg: error processing package librtmp1:i386 (--install):
 package librtmp1:i386 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2 cannot be configured because librtmp1:amd64 is at a different version (2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7)
dpkg: error processing package librtmp1:amd64 (--install):
 package librtmp1:amd64 2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7 cannot be configured because librtmp1:i386 is at a different version (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 librtmp1:i386
 librtmp1:amd64

# apt policy librtmp1:i386
librtmp1:i386:
  Installed: 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2
  Candidate: 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2
  Version table:
 *** 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

# apt policy librtmp1
librtmp1:
  Installed: 2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7
  Candidate: 2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```

The versions are different. I downgraded librtmp1 to the same version of the i386 package and mark as hold.

```
# apt-get install librtmp1=2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  android-libcrypto-utils giblib1 imagemagick-7-common libb2-1 libbotan-2-17 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libffms2-4 libgdl-3-5
  libgdl-3-common libigdgmm11 libmagick++-7-5 libmagickcore-7-9 libmagickwand-7-9 libmwaw-0.3-3 libnumbertext-1.0-0
  libnumbertext-data libopencsd0 liborcus-0.16-0 liborcus-parser-0.16-0 libplacebo104 libqrcodegencpp1 libraqm0
  libsixel1 libtspi1 libzip4 linux-headers-5.10.0-10-common linux-headers-5.10.0-16-common
  linux-headers-5.10.0-9-common linux-perf-5.10 python3-cssutils python3-pyxattr python3-toml rtmpdump sse3-support
  vapoursynth vapoursynth-ffms2 youtube-dl
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  librtmp1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 60.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 librtmp1 amd64 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2 [60.8 kB]
Fetched 60.8 kB in 0s (582 kB/s)  
dpkg: warning: downgrading librtmp1:amd64 from 2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7 to 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2
(Reading database ... 424608 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../librtmp1_2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2) over (2:2.4~20160119.gitfa8646dae-dmo7) ...
Setting up librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2) ...
Setting up librtmp1:i386 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2+b2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u5) ...

# apt-mark hold librtmp1
```

From there, I could install wine32.